# Flask routing error with custom decorator

Tags: python, flask

blueprint.py

```
### Standard Library Imports ###

################################

### 3rd Party Imports ###
from flask import Blueprint
################################

### Local Imports ###

################################


main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
from .views import *
```

views.py:

```
@main.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
@check_confirmation
def index():
    users=None
    form = UserSearchForm()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_month = now.month
    current_year = now.year
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(current_year, current_month)[1]
    calendar_info = {
        "days_in_month": days_in_month,
        "current_year": current_year,
        "current_month": get_month(),
    }
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        searched = form.username.data
        return redirect(url_for("main.search", searched_user=searched))
    return render_template('/main/main_index.html',
                           **calendar_info,
                           months=months,
                           users=users,
                           form=form)
```

check confirmation decorator:

```
def check_confirmation(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.confirmed:
            flash("Please confirm your account")
            return redirect(url_for("main.unconfirmed"))
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

what's interesting is. using class based views the decorator works fine but not for function based views. infact all custom decorators I make with flask using function based views and blueprints returns a `routing build error`

any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

well as it turns out

```
def check_confirmation(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.confirmed:
            flash("Please confirm your account")
            return redirect(url_for("main.unconfirmed"))
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

you need to import the wraps function from the `functools` library
I didn't think you'd need to because I thought the `wraps` decorator just gets the info on the function. but my guess is it does this to differentiate from a regularly defined `function` vs a `view function`. Is my guess right?

but judging from this I'd assume that flask introspects the functions and im pretty sure it does.

but what bothered me was when you use `class based` views the `check_confirmation` doesn't need the `@wraps`

Comment: Thanks, just stumbled upon this one.